# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'doThings' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have an array of nodes that will beautifully be populated with `obj`s

```
var nodesArray = [];

var obj = function(nodeSpan){
    this.nodeS = nodeSpan;

    this.doThings = function(){
            console.log(this.nodeS);
    };
}
```

I put lots of `obj`'s into `nodeArray`

```
var newObj = new obj(thisIsASpan) ///trust me that's a span
nodesArray.push(newObj);
//etc
```

I call a map function on each node adding an event listener.

```
Array.prototype.map.call(nodesArray, function(obj, index) {
        obj.nodeS.addEventListener('click', function(obj, index) {
                nodesArray[index].doThings(); ////Throws error in title.
        });
});
```

I click on one of the damn spans.

I get error in title, I then walk to break room, I then have breakdown.

Comment: I would start by console.loging out the nodesArray and then see if it is working the same way you think it is .. then console.log index and obj out

Comment: @jdave the index was correctly passed to the `addEventListener`

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use `Array.prototype.map.call` when your variable contains a real array. Just use `nodesArray.map(...)`. The complex syntax is only needed for array-like objects.

Comment: @Barmar I prefer this way, that way it always works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be adding obj and index when you are defining the click, those are being set when the click is being fired. In your case the first argument is the event object and the second is undefined since click only has one argument.

```
Array.prototype.map.call(nodesArray, function(obj, index) {
        obj.nodeS.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                nodesArray[index].doThings(); 
        });
});
```

Comment: I hug @epascarello

Comment: But seriously, why does addEventListener have access to the index then? And why wouldn't I be able to pass index explicitly?

Comment: because the variables are in same block scope.